# haskell check for balanced tree

Tags: haskell, tree

How do I check this tree is balanced?

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)

size :: Tree a -> Int
size (Leaf n)    = 1
size (Node x z) = size x + size z + 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
isBalancedTree :: Tree a -> Bool
isBalancedTree (Node l r) = abs (size l - size r) <= 1
                            && isBalancedTree l && isBalancedTree r
isBalancedTree _ = False
```

Answer (score 3):

A leaf is balanced, so the last line should really evaluate to `True`, which leads you to:

```
isBalancedTree :: Tree a -> Bool
isBalancedTree (Leaf _) = True
isBalancedTree (Node l r) = 
    let diff = abs (size l - size r) in
    diff <= 1 && isBalancedTree l && isBalancedTree r
```

Comment: I think it's pretty standard to allow balanced trees to have branches that differ in size by one. In some cases it even means the two branches differ in _height_ by at most one, or other relaxations (e.g. I would call a red-black tree balanced, and all it promises is that the deepest leaf of any subtree is no  more than twice as deep as the shallowest leaf). So it really depends on context.

Comment: Calling isBalancedTree (Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3)) (Leaf 2)) should equate to True, but this is not the case, the output is False?

Comment: @user3633383 Erm, from the first one you have two subtrees which are of size 3 and 1 respectively. It should return `False` in that case, and it does.

Comment: Whether a binary tree is balanced or not doesn't actually depend on the values in the leaves (they could be anything), it only cares about how many leaves and nodes there are.

See: [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees[link]

(Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3)) (Leaf 2))

 __|__
_|_  2
1 3

This tree is balanced because you can't move any elements to reduce the height.

(Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3))) (Leaf 2))

  ___|___
__|__   2
1  _|_
   1 3

This tree is not balanced.

So, ignore the leaf values and only worry about the leaf count and the depth.